# How can I use Acrobat Pro to determine whether an image is rasterized?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

How can I check on whether an image (PDF image file) is rasterized, using Adobe Acrobat Pro?

Comment: yes ... but can you please tell how using acrobat pro?

Comment: You can try to zoom in as much as possible, and see if the image becomes pixelated.  If it remains smooth (and the line edges remain nicely anti-aliased), then it is probably still a vector image.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what application created the PDF file, then just regard the meta-data of the PDF file.

If you mean an embedded image, you should extract it with one of the many available applications, and you might strike it lucky and find that it has embedded meta-data, by using an image editor.

Comment: I don't really care what application created the PDF file. Just by opening a PDF file in acrobat pro, and seeing its properties (or anything else?), how can I tell if it has any rasterized component in it?

Comment: If the image was included as-is, it would probably have meta-data specifying the application that created it, same as the PDF. A program such as IfranView can show the image information. Try in acrobat pro right-click on the image and see if it lets you have the info or extract the image (copy is not enough). If not, a [quick google](http://www.google.fr/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1606&bih=1001&q=pdf+extract+images&btnG=Google+Search) got me [this](http://download.cnet.com/Some-PDF-Image-Extract/3000-2079_4-10836441.html), but there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

In Acrobat Pro 8:

Choose the menu entry
Advanced / Print Production / Preflight: Under "PDF analysis": "Show all bitmaps".